# Create list of dictionaries from text lines and duplicate items

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

Get stucked with a relatively  simple task.
Got a text file, need to do a **list of dictionaries**. If the first item of the line is the same, items from other lines should belong to the same dictionary.
**Please see text file and preferred outcome.**

*.txt*

```
739883332,amenity,recycling
739883346,amenity,recycling
835250417,payment:maestro,yes
835250417,payment:mastercard,yes
835250417,payment:visa,yes
3259847948,recycling:cans,no
3259847948,recycling:clothes,no
```

*So far I have got…*

```
for i in line:          
    i=i.strip() 
    i=i.split(',')
    ID=i[0] 
    key=i[1]
    val=i[2]
    dict['ID']=ID
    dict[key]=val
```

*Preferred outcome:*

```
[{'ID':739883332},{'amenity':'recycling'}]
[{'ID':739883346},{'amenity':'recycling'}]
[{'ID':835250417},{'payment:maestro':'yes'},{'payment:mastercard':'yes'},{'payment:visa':'yes'}]
[{'ID':3259847948},{'recycling:cans':'no'},{'recycling:clothes':'no'}]
```

Comment: `{payment:maestro:yes}` This is invalid syntax. Dictionaries are made up of key:value pairs.

Comment: {recycling:cans:no} syntax is wrong, as well as dict['nodeID:']=ID, please correct it

Comment: You are right, but in my case it will lokk like {'payment:maestro':'yes'}

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

```
def merge_lists(d1list, d2list, key):
merged = {}
for item in d1list+d2list:
    if item[key] in merged:
        merged[item[key]].update(item)
    else:
        merged[item[key]] = item
return [val for (_, val) in merged.items()]

for i in line:
    dict={}
    i=i.strip() 
    i=i.split(',')
    ID=i[0] 
    key=i[3]
    val=i[4]    
    dict['nodeID:']=ID
    dict[key]=val
    if ID not in list:
        list.append(ID)
        d1list.append(dict)
    else:
        d2list.append(dict)

final_list = merge_lists(d1list, d2list, 'nodeID:')
```

Will appreciate for code optimisation notes.